# Typescript classes bundle with webpack

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I have written a project on Typescript and setup to bundle it with webpack.
Main functionality is wrapped in one `Main` class, but it imports also other classes.
Need to export `Main` class and all dependent in to one `bundle.js` library to use in in other sites.

I've tried to bundle classes in separate project (without webpack just tsc).

this is tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "amd",
    "target": "ES2015",
    "declaration": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "outFile": "./dist/index.js",
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

but it is not usable since the error:

> ReferenceError: define is not defined
>   compilled code contains edfine
>   define("Globals", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {

and also with webpack but not sure have correct setup 
the bundle file start with

```
(function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
```

in other words I have some classes:

- Main.ts
- A.ts
- B.ts
- C.ts

and I expected to get `bundle.js` file and use like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="mylib/dist/index.js"></script>
//...
var a = new Main();
```

but stuck with understanding how it should Typescript and Jsvascript work together.

Will appreciate any help

Update:
Managed to solve with webpack. `Main` is asccessible from entry `app.ts` when compiled. So inside `app.ts` added `window.onload` handler and assigned class to `window` scope.

```
window.onload = function () {
    window['MyClass'] = Main;
```

May be missing something but couldn't find good documentation about writing library on TypeScript for browsers.

Update2:
Ok. found answer. webpack option `library` works fine.

```
output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: __dirname + "/dist",
    library: "MyMainClass"
},
```

also had to change `tsconfig.json` `target` option from `es6` to `es5`

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": { "*": ["types/*"] },
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es6",
            "dom.iterable",
            "scripthost"
        ],
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5"
    },
    "exclude": [
      "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Typescript is a javascript **superset**, meaning it can't be interpreted directly, but needs to be **compiled** first (to plain javascript). So, it's just that typescript will be, in fact, plain javascript, once compiled. If your library is targeted to be used for the web, `module` key should be `es2015`. Also, usually, you should have an `index` file **exporting** everything needed. You should read this section of the typescript documentation about modules resolution: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#module-resolution-strategies

Comment: @briosheje es2015 - is written as target value in tsconfig, setting es2015 for module  leaves ts-code as is. ofcourse compiled, it was a question how to make this plain js code, its all written above.